# Generate random data based on correlation matrix for multiple timesteps

Tags: time-series, correlation, error

Assume a p x n data matrix  (e.g. p independent samples of n variables).
The n variables are correlated according to a correlation matrix $\rho$.

Now if you consider the data matrix as some state t (t=time)  and
based on this state I would like to calculate the next timestep (t+1).

Therefore the correlation matrix would be allowed to have values < 1 in the
diagonal, which means that the diagonal elements would indicate the influence from
each variable $x_{p,i}[t]$ on $x_{p,i}[t+1]$.

So I would be interested to find a function f like this:

$x_{p,i}[t+1] = f(x_{p,i}[t],\rho)$

so that the p x n data matrix  consisting of the $x_{p,i}[t+1]$
replicates the $\rho_{ij}$ (except the diagonal element).

f should be something like this:

$x_{i,j}[t+1] = \sum_{(k=1\ldots n)}\rho_{i,k} \cdot x_{kj}[t] + e_{i,j}.$

This means specifically, I not only want to calculate a data matrix,
that replicates the correlation matrix as such, but also to let
each observation be depending on its own state and linear dependent
on the previous state of all the intercorrelated variables of its own state.

For ease one can assume that the p variables are distributed normal and $e_{ij}$ are independent and distributed with mean$(e_{i,j}) = 0 $. Then for a numerical simulation
it would be interesting  to find a formula to calculate the variance/standard deviation of each of the j variables (sd($e_{[.,j]} = ?).$

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I generated another question with code in R 
for clarification:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/514348/generate-random-data-based-on-correlation-matrix-for-multiple-timesteps-in-r

Comment: The basic idea to calculate the matrix elements seems to be o.k. My solution is described here code examples in R: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/514348/generate-random-data-based-on-correlation-matrix-for-multiple-timesteps-in-r

Comment: Please don't spread your posts around the site, Mike: you can edit your original post; you can comment on your posts; and you can answer the original tool.  See our [help] for more information on how CV works.

Answer (score 0):

There are two important issues, I guess now the code works:

(1) there was a simple error in the code. it is nmot:

```
newData[p,i] = data[p,i] + err
```

but
newData[p,i] = newData[p,i] + err

With this it works better (of course!), but still not perfect,
because my random generator did just use rnorm.
This should lead to uncorrelated samples but with sample sizes
liek 1000 rows there are still random correlations with error and data.
So the resulting correlations cannot be perfect just because
var(x + err) = var(x) + var (err)  + 2*cov(x,err)
and cov(x,err) > 0.

So to get closer to the desired correlations the random errors have
to be compensated for the error.

I found a good working example for this here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930211/generate-uncorrelated-variables-each-well-correlated-with-existing-response-vari

So with a modification

r <- cbind( c(1, 0),
c(0.0, 1))

the advanced random generator provides random errors
which come close to 0.

And with this modifications the sampeld  correlation matrix now
is sufficient close to the predefined values.