# Generate random data based on correlation matrix for multiple timesteps in R

Tags: time-series, correlation, error

This question is related to a more symbolic formulation of the problem.
Here I will post code in R I tried out so far:

```
calcCorrSums <- function (data, corrMat,  oldMean, oldVar, N) {
  newData  = matrix(NA, nrow(data), ncol(data))  
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    for (j in 1:N) { 
      xs = 0    
      for (k in 1:N) {
        r = corrMat[j,k]
        xs = xs + r * (data[i,k]-oldMean[k]) / oldVar[k]
      } #for k 
      newData[i,j] = (xs  + oldMean[j]) * oldVar[j]
    } # j 
  } # for i 
  return (newData)
}
```

This function generates a dataset without random errors.
It is called by the function below, which after this
calculation adds the random errors to each data point:

```
 getNextStepData <- function (data,corrMat, N) {
   oldStat  = calcVarMeanAndVariances(data,N)
   newData = calcCorrSums(data,corrMat, oldStat$m, oldStat$v, N)
   newStat = calcVarMeanAndVariances(newData,N)
 
   for (i in 1:N)  {  
     errVar = oldStat$v[i] - newStat$v[i]
     if (errVar<=0) {
       stop(sprintf("Error: errVar = %f for var[%i]",errVar,i))
     } 
     errSd = sqrt(errVar)
     for (p in 1:nrow(data)) {
       err = getRand(errSd)
       newData[p,i] = data[p,i] + err
     } #for p
   } # for i
 
   return (newData)
 }
```

The problem is: my first simulations can replicate the structure
of the correlation matrix somehow, but not close enough.
So something still seems to be wrong.

An example of the original correlation matrix:

```
  0.80 0.20 0.00 0.00 0.20
  0.20 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.00
  0.00 0.00 0.70 0.20 0.00
  0.00 0.00 0.20 0.50 0.00
  0.20 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.40
```

Here is the correlation matrix derived from
new data:

```
   0.94  0.14  0.01  0.02  0.16
   0.18  0.77  0.02  0.01 -0.01
  -0.02  0.04  0.85  0.14 -0.03
   0.01  0.03  0.16  0.78 -0.03
   0.20 -0.01 -0.02 -0.01  0.76
```

The simulation was done with 1000 cases ( = nrows of data).

The initial data were generated with the MASS library,
which could replicated the dataset almost perfect.

Thank you for any help!